# How do we do a purge of the database in between junit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

Below are some of the classes that support @TestContainers functionality

```
package com.changeorama.solidify;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
....

@Testcontainers
public class AbstractTest {
    
    @Container
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>();


    static {
        postgres.start();
    }
    
    @Test
    void testPostgresIsRunning() {
        assertTrue(postgres.isRunning());
    }
    
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void postgreSQLProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgres::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgres::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgres::getPassword);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

```
package com.changeorama.solidify.repository;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
....

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class CompartmentRepositoryTest extends AbstractTest{
    
    
    @Autowired
    CompartmentRepository compRepository;
    
    @Test
    void testSaveCompartment() {
      //Load test data
        CompartmentEntity comp = new CompartmentEntity();
        comp.setCompartmentId(12);
        comp.setCompartmentName(“Comp abc”);
        comp.setCompartmentSize(12);

        compRepository(comp);
        
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void testGetAllCompartments() {

        List<CompartmentEntity> comps = compRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(comps.isEmpty(), is(false));
    }
    
   
    
}
```

Is there a way clean up the data in between tests that run in the same test suite with the @Testcontainers approach?

Do we have an ability to do a purge of the database in between tests?

Is there anyway we can do a manual purge of data if not possible with @TestContainers?

Answer (score 2):

1. Annotate your test class with `@Transactional`

   ```
   @Slf4j
   @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
   @DataJpaTest
   @Transactional
   @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
   public class CompartmentRepositoryTest extends AbstractTest{
     //then your code
   }
   ```

When a test class is annotated with `@Transactional` each test method within
that class hierarchy runs within a transaction that is by default it will **rollback automatically** after completion.

***Note that***

- `@Transactional` is not supported on test lifecycle methods.
- Tests that are annotated with `@Transactional` but have the propagation attribute set to `NOT_SUPPORTED` **(`@Transactional = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED`)** are not run within a transaction.

2. You can use `@Rollback` on class level or test method

   ```
   @Test
   @Rollback(true)
   void testSaveCompartment() {}
   ```

- Rollback indicates whether the transaction should be rolled back after the test method has completed.

Comment: Will the usage of Transactional work fine in a parallel test execution? Is there any manual way I can delete only the data in all the tables (not the tables themselves) in the AfterEach method?

Comment: yes, it will work fine.  @Deadpool solution should work if you want to delete test data

Comment: I mean check given answer from  Deadpool

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@BeforeEach` and `deleteAll` method from CompartmentRepository (assuming it implements JPARepository) to purge table before every test, so that each test start's with it's own data

```
@AfterEach
public void setup() {
    compRepository.deleteAll()
 }
```